# For while loop C++ basic interest calculator

Tags: c++, for-loop

For your 21st birthday, your grandmother opens a savings account for you and deposits $1000 into the account.  The savings account pays a 3% interest on the account balance.  If you don't deposit any more money into the account, and you don't withdraw any money from the account, how much will your savings account be worth at the end of 1 through 5 years?

Create a program that gives you the answers.  You can calculate the answers using the following formula: b = p * (1 + r)n .  In the formula, p is the principal (the amount of the deposit), r is the annual interest rate (3%), n is the number of years (1 through 5), and b is the balance in the savings account at the end of the nth year.
Use a for loop.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

This is what I have so far and all I get is an infinite loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
// Inputs //

double princ = 0.0;
double rate = 0.0;
int years = 0;
int year = 1;
double total = 0.0;

// Ask User For INFO //

cout << "What is the principle? ";
cin >> princ;
cout << "What is the rate in decimal? ";
cin >> rate;
cout << "how many years? ";
cin >> years;



for (double total; total = princ*(1+rate)*year;)
{
cout << "The balance after year " << year << " is "<< total << endl << endl;
year += 1;
}

while((years + 1)!= year);

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `void main()`, `system("pause")`, ... where do people learn this stuff?

Comment: @dreamlax When students are first learning, and they happen to be using Visual Studio, they get confused because Visual Studio automatically closes the debugging console as soon as the program ends, so instructors and sample exercises frequently add `system("PAUSE");` at the end, which (on Windows) causes a message like "Press any key to continue..." to be printed, and waits for an input before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood how the for loop works. It is used to do something a certain number of times, in your example it would be appropriate to loop over a certain number of years. Something like this:

```
double interest = 1.0 * rate:
double accumulated = 1.0 * interest;

for (auto i=1; i < years; ++i) {
    accumulated *= interest;
    cout << "The balance after year " << i << " is " << (princ * accumulated) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you somehow mixed up your `for` and `while` loop.

Instead of

```
for (double total; total = princ*(1+rate)*year;)
{
cout << "The balance after year " << year << " is "<< total << endl << endl;
year += 1;
}

while((years + 1)!= year);
```

You'd probably want something like this:

```
for (double total; (years +1) != year; total = princ*(1+rate)*year)
{
cout << "The balance after year " << year << " is "<< total << endl << endl;
year += 1;
}
```

Also your `main` function shouldn't return `void` as already noted in the comments and should instead be `int main()`